# Accessing Web Reference WSDL in Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

Sorry this is a newbie question, I have added a Service Reference to my project and in my code behind file I have added a reference but I can't seem to instantiate the service object.

If I create proxy classes I am able to instantiate the service NetSuiteService class (NetSuiteAuthenticator.com.netsuite.webservices1.NetSuiteService) with reference, but would like to know where I am going wrong using the Add Service Reference. Using Add Service Reference...

```
    using CustomerPortal.ServiceReference1;

    namespace CustomerPortal
    {
        public partial class NetSuiteWSTest : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                NetSuiteService service = new NetSuiteService(); // <-- Cannot find NetSuiteService     
                Passport nsPassport = new Passport();
                nsPassport.account = "";
                nsPassport.email = "";            
                RecordRef nsRole = new RecordRef();
                nsRole.internalId = "3";
                nsPassport.role = nsRole;
                nsPassport.password = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have my answer! I remade the project and it started working! This was the best way I could do it.

It was lucky that this was the start of the project